# Game Features section in Play Store app's detailed view

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

If you search for [Super Stickman Golf 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noodlecake.ssg2), you will see a section called "Game Features" that shows which features are available (multiplayer and achievements).

But my game [Minesweeper 3D](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiirecords.minesweeper3d), which also has Google Play Games support (leaderboards and achievements) doesn't have this section.

The question is: **Do I have to do anything or is it google that manually adds this section for chosen apps?**

---

Super Stickman Golf 2 Screenshot:

[image: Super Stickman Golf 2]

---

Minesweeper 3D Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be automatic. Once you reach a certain number of users and API calls, the badges should appear.

Comment: I checked the API console: Total requests = 11.17k, Requests/day = 1.83k peak 398.89 average. Am I very far from it?

Comment: @thiagolr Your game now has the badges - if not a secret, when did they appear?

Comment: As Bruno said, it appeared after a while, but I don't know exactly when!

Answer (score 0):

I  was  so  happy  when  the  icons apear  in my  apps,  but  the worse  things  is  that  right  now  I  have few trafic  and  them desappear  again.  Conclusion, google  is manipulating  it  and  using  like filtering.