# Why in "Google Play Games" is not shown "Leaderboard" and "Features" tabs?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have implemented Leaderboards and Achievements in my game.
Before "Play Games" app update I can visualize leaderboard tab, but now I cannot.
For example:

[image: Plants vs Zombie screen]

In my game:
[image: My game screen]

But when I launch

```
     startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(),      LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

in my game it works fine.

I don't understand why is not shown in "play games" application.
Can you help me?

Comment: I found a problem like this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917854/game-features-section-in-play-store-apps-detailed-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing a leaderboard intent inside your app is different from the google play store showing it on their website.

Your app has to have had enough attention for those badges to appear.